# Extract text from long string with power query

Tags: powerquery

Is there a way where you can extract a text and create a new column if a specific text is in the long string. Like if I have this long comma separated string where sometimes Bluetooth is in it and sometimes not but I want to create a new column with Bluetooth if it's in the long string. Is there a way you can do it in power query?

I know I can comma separate the long string but there some of it that is supposed to have commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify but in general here is two ways. One looks for a phrase anywhere in text, one for a phrase within each separate set of comma-separated text

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom1", each if Text.Contains([Column1],"bluetooth") then [Column1] else null),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", each Text.Combine(try List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Text.Split([Custom1],","), each if Text.Contains(_,"bluetooth") then _ else null)) otherwise {},",")    )
in  #"Added Custom1"
```

[image]